# Is it safe to run a relay-only node?

Tags: relays, legal

I have some spare bandwidth **at home** that I am willing to donate to the TOR project. I am thinking about running a relay-only / non-exit node, but only if it is completely safe and trouble-free for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for considering running a relay. Generally it's problem-free to act as a relay with a `reject *:*` exit policy. That said, there are some things you'd be best to check first.

1. Local laws that might apply, even if you don't exit traffic there's a possibility that some kind of "anti-proxying" law covers it. *(A lot of computer-related legislation is vague and no longer fit for purpose. [CryptoLaw.org](http://www.cryptolaw.org/) might help clarify some, but maybe cotact a lawyer.)*
2. Does it violate anything in your ISP's Terms of Service or Acceptable Use Policy, etc?
3. Can you provide enough bandwidth to be helpful to the Tor network?
4. Even if it's not strictly illegal, is it safe for you? Don't play chicken with fascists lightly.
5. If something *did* happen (this is pretty uncommon if you're not exiting traffic but there's no limits to certain law enforcement agencies misunderstanding of technologies), they're might kick in your door and take all your computer related stuff because it's at home. See point 4.